# Restore Team Foundation Server from SQL Server bak files

Tags: sql-server, tfs

I accidentally deleted the wrong project in TFS 2018 Update 2. Then I found out that we do not use the regular backups for TFS. We just backup the databases.

On a test server I have installed tfs and restored the databases to SQL Server.  However it will not allow me to configure tfs with those tables.

What can I do to get the data back? I do not need a perfect restore, but I would like to get the code and if possible the work items. Even getting the data directly from the tables is fine, but I am not sure how the tables are setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed TFS 2018 on a new server and was able to use the sql backup files.  I then exported the code and then imported it into the existing server.

Answer (score 1):

Unless someone from Microsoft provides you with specific SQL scripts, any attempt to restore the deleted project by copying data from one database to another is most likely going to accomplish two things:

1. Break your TFS installation
2. Leave you in an unsupported state

So **don't do that**.

You'll need to do a complete restore of the TFS instance, which should be possible assuming you have backups of all of the TFS databases (configuration and project collections). There is extensive documentation on how to do that.

Comment: Thanks.  I do not want to restore into the existing TFS.  I want to manually bring down the code, then upload that to a new project on the existing server.  I need to restore the sql backups to a test server so that I can get to the code.  That is the issue I am having, we did not use the standard tfs backup.  We only backed up the sql databases.  There are a million tutorials and I cannot find one that works with preexisting backups, only a plan if you want to make a backup.

Comment: All the TFS backup tool does is run a standard SQL backup with an additional transaction marker. Your backups are *probably* fine if they were taken at the same time. You should be able to follow the standard instructions for cloning a TFS instance on new hardware, just with the database backups being manually restored instead of restored through the wizard.